# How to code a function that enables the system to automatically assign an unique id based on the date the data is inserted

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to code a function that can automatically assign the booking ID to each record inserted.
The format for the booking ID that I wanted is BYYMMDD-99(Eg: B211202-01 for the first record saved)
This function will replace the previous way that requires the user to manually input the booking ID and the function will be in

```
Private Function AutoBKGID() As Boolean

End Function
```

---

```
Data types: 
INBKG_RECID - int,
INBKG_BKGID - varchar(30),
INBKG_BKGDT - date,
INBKG_USRID - varchar(20),
INBKG_MATCD - varchar(30),
INBKG_BKGQT - decimal (12, 3),
INBKG_STSFG - varchar(2)
```

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 for this program.
Below is my current complete code if needed for my question, I'm looking for some ideas that can achieve the requirement mentioned or produce results similar to it. Thanks for any answers in advance.

```
Public Class frmINBKG
    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
      Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
      Call ClearDetails()
    End Sub

    Private Function SaveRecord() As Boolean
      Dim strSQL As String

    Try
      If numRECID.Value = 0 Then
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO INBKG_TBL ("
        strSQL &= "INBKG_BKGID, INBKG_BKGDT, INBKG_USRID, "
        strSQL &= "INBKG_MATCD, INBKG_BKGQT, INBKG_STSFG) "
        strSQL &= "VALUES ('" & txtBKGID.Text & "', '" & gfSQLDate(dtBKGDT.Value) & "', '" & txtUSRID.Text & "', "
        strSQL &= "'" & txtBKGMAT.Text & "'," & numBKGQT.Value & ",  '1')"
     Else
        strSQL = "UPDATE INBKG_TBL "
        strSQL &= "SET INBKG_BKGID = '" & txtBKGID.Text & "', INBKG_BKGDT = '" & gfSQLDate(dtBKGDT.Value) & "', "
        strSQL &= "INBKG_USRID = '" & txtUSRID.Text & "', INBKG_MATCD = '" & txtBKGMAT.Text & "', "
        strSQL &= "INBKG_BKGQT = " & numBKGQT.Value & " "
        strSQL &= "WHERE INBKG_RECID = " & numRECID.Value & " "
     End If
     Return DBExecute(strSQL)

  Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SaveRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Return False
  End Try
End Function

Private Function DeleteRecord() As Boolean
  Dim strSQL As String

  Try
     strSQL = "DELETE FROM INBKG_TBL "
     strSQL &= "WHERE INBKG_RECID = " & numRECID.Value & ""

     Return DBExecute(strSQL)

  Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "DeleteRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Return False
  End Try
End Function

Private Function InkReady(intRECID) As Boolean
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim dt As DataTable

  Try
     strSQL = "SELECT * FROM INBKG_TBL "
     strSQL &= "WHERE INBKG_RECID = " & intRECID & " "
     strSQL &= "AND INBKG_STSFG > 1"
     dt = ExecProc(strSQL)
     InkReady = (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

  Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "InkReady", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Return False
  End Try
End Function

Private Function AutoBKGID() As Boolean
  ***
End Function

Private Function ValidDetails() As Boolean
   If txtBKGID.Text = String.Empty Then
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid Booking ID", "ValidDetails", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
      txtBKGID.Focus()
      Return False
   End If

  If DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Now.Date, dtBKGDT.Value) < 0 Then
     MessageBox.Show("Previous date is not allowed!", "ValidDetails", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Return False
  End If

  If txtUSRID.Text = String.Empty Then
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid User ID!", "ValidDetails", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Return False
  End If

  If txtBKGMAT.Text = String.Empty Then
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Booking Material!", "ValidDetails", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Return False
  End If

  If numBKGQT.Value = 0 Then
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Booking Quantity!", "ValidDetails", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Return False
  End If

  Return True
End Function

Private Sub ClearDetails()
  txtBKGID.Text = String.Empty
  dtBKGDT.Value = Date.Today
  txtUSRID.Text = String.Empty
  txtBKGMAT.Text = String.Empty
  numBKGQT.Value = 0
  numRECID.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub RefreshGrid()
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim dt As DataTable
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To dgvBKG.Rows.Count
     dgvBKG.Rows.Remove(dgvBKG.Rows(0))
  Next

  strSQL = "Select INBKG_STSFG, Case INBKG_STSFG When 1 Then 'New' WHEN 2 THEN 'Ready' ELSE 'Complete' END AS STSFG, "
  strSQL &= "INBKG_BKGID, INBKG_BKGDT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), INBKG_BKGDT, 103), INBKG_USRID, "
  strSQL &= "INBKG_MATCD, INBKG_BKGQT, INBKG_RECID "
  strSQL &= "FROM INBKG_TBL "
  strSQL &= "WHERE INBKG_STSFG In ('1', '2')"
  strSQL &= "ORDER BY INBKG_BKGDT, INBKG_RECID"
  dt = ExecProc(strSQL)

  With dgvBKG
     .DataSource = dt
     .Columns(0).Visible = False

     .Columns(1).Visible = True
     .Columns(1).Width = 60
     .Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
     .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Status"

     .Columns(2).Visible = True
     .Columns(2).Width = 120
     .Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
     .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Booking ID"

     .Columns(3).Visible = False

     .Columns(4).Visible = True
     .Columns(4).Width = 120
     .Columns(4).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
     .Columns(4).HeaderText = "Booking Date"

     .Columns(5).Visible = True
     .Columns(5).Width = 125
     .Columns(5).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
     .Columns(5).HeaderText = "User ID"

     .Columns(6).Visible = True
     .Columns(6).Width = 250
     .Columns(6).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
     .Columns(6).HeaderText = "Material"

     .Columns(7).Visible = True
     .Columns(7).Width = 80
     .Columns(7).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
     .Columns(7).HeaderText = "Quantity"

     .Columns(8).Visible = False
     .Columns(8).Width = 50
     .Columns(8).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
     .Columns(8).HeaderText = "RECID"

     .AutoResizeRows()
     .Refresh()
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub frmINEADJ_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
   Dim blnChildFormExists As Boolean

   For Each ChildForm As Form In Me.ParentForm.MdiChildren
      If ChildForm.Name <> Me.Name Then
        blnChildFormExists = True
        Exit For
      End If
   Next
   If Not blnChildFormExists Then Me.ParentForm.Controls("Panel1").Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
  If Not AutoBKGID() Then Exit Sub
  If Not ValidDetails() Then Exit Sub

  If InkReady(numRECID.Value) Then
     MessageBox.Show("This record cannot be updated because it's already prepared.", "SaveRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Exit Sub
  End If

  If Not SaveRecord() Then
     MessageBox.Show("Record fail to save!", "SaveRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Exit Sub
  End If

  MessageBox.Show("Record save successfully.", "SaveRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
  Call RefreshGrid()
  Call ClearDetails()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
  Call RefreshGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub frmINBKG_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  dgvBKG.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent
  dgvBKG.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub

Private Sub dgvBKG_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dgvBKG.CellFormatting
  If Not dgvBKG.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "STSFG" Then Exit Sub

  If dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_STSFG").Value = 2 Then
     If e.Value.ToString = "Ready" Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White
     End If
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub frmINBKG_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
  Call RefreshGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub dgvBKG_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBKG.CellDoubleClick
  If dgvBKG.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

  txtBKGID.Text = dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_BKGID").Value
  dtBKGDT.Value = dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_BKGDT").Value
  txtUSRID.Text = dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_USRID").Value
  txtBKGMAT.Text = dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_MATCD").Value
  numBKGQT.Value = dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_BKGQT").Value
  numRECID.Value = dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_RECID").Value
  txtSTSFG.Text = dgvBKG.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("INBKG_STSFG").Value
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
  If numRECID.Value = 0 Then
     MessageBox.Show("Please select a record to delete.", "DeleteRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Exit Sub
  End If

  If InkReady(numRECID.Value) Then
     MessageBox.Show("This record cannot be deleted because it's already prepared.", "DeleteRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Exit Sub
  End If

  If Not DeleteRecord() Then
     MessageBox.Show("Record not deleted.", "DeleteRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
     Exit Sub
  End If

  MessageBox.Show("Record deleted successfully.", "DeleteRecord", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
  Call RefreshGrid()
  Call ClearDetails()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You’ve not mentioned your db but most have an inbuilt mechanic for Id values you would probably be far better off using over this, or at least a guid.  What your plan here can work if implemented properly but a heap of overhead for something that already exists

Comment: I am guessing you are creating a primary key value. It is bad design to have a PK with any meaningful data. The only purpose of the PK is to uniquely identify the record. Use an identity field for the PK and add a column for Date/Time of booking.

Comment: I guess you missed the requirement for a Minimal amount of code for your question. It is Minimal, Complete and Reproducible.

Comment: Never concatenate strings to build sql strings. Always use parameters to avoid sql injection.